# Emptying many span elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these span on my webpage and i am trying to empty their innerHTML on page load.

But I don't want to do `document.getElelmentById().innerHTML = '';` for all `100` span instead if there is a way where i can empty them using their class name.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $a = document.getElementsByClassName("char_counter");
  for (i = 0; i < $a.length; i++) {
    console.log($a[i]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="char_counter" id="one">1</span>
<span class="char_counter" id="two">2</span>
<span class="char_counter" id="three">3</span>
<span class="char_counter" id="four">4</span>
```

Comment: The question body doesn't seem to have anything to do with the title. Where does the id attribute come into it?

Comment: @Quentin Perhaps OP was confused, he presumed that he has to loop over all elements and get `id` and then update `innerHTML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to loop over all the elements and setting `innerHTML` to empty string.

You can use `html()` or `text()` to set their `innerHTML` as empty.

```
$('.char_counter').html('');
```

will select all the elements having class `char_counter` and set their `innerHTML` to empty string.

More specifically, you can also use

```
$('span.char_counter').html('');
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.char_counter').html('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="char_counter" id="one">1</span>
<span class="char_counter" id="two">2</span>
<span class="char_counter" id="three">3</span>
<span class="char_counter" id="four">4</span>
```

Comment: Woah... Did you answer before me? `:O`

Comment: @PraveenKumar 2 minutes :P

Comment: @PraveenKumar It's happen many times with me i can't read full question but at sudden i got an answer form Tushar

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the following code:

```
$(".char_counter").html('');
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".char_counter").html('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="char_counter" id="one">1</span>
<span class="char_counter" id="two">2</span>
<span class="char_counter" id="three">3</span>
<span class="char_counter" id="four">4</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure **JavaScript** way to do it:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("char_counter");
for (i in spans) {
  spans[i].innerHTML = "";
};
```

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("char_counter");
for (i in spans) {
  spans[i].innerHTML = "";
};
```

```html
<span class="char_counter" id="one">1</span>
<span class="char_counter" id="two">2</span>
<span class="char_counter" id="three">3</span>
<span class="char_counter" id="four">4</span>
```

And this is the **jQuery** way:

```
$('span.char_counter').html('');
```